# Quad sphere subdivision algorithm

Tags: procedural-generation, procedural, sphere, quadtree

I like to generate some planets like Kerbal Space Program does. By some videos of the developers I know that they use a quadsphere, which consists of six “entities” as a minimum. These are all plane meshes, which get subdivided the closer you get. This allows a ground to orbit level of detail. However, I have some problems understanding this subdivision algorithm:

1. Since I have six separate meshes, how do I know where I have to subdivide them, if they are all separate?
2. If I always just subdivide the quad the camera is over and I end up with something like this:

[image: Image1]

even though I want something like:

[image: this].

So how can I ensure a sense full 2:1 subdivision with neighbour quads?

Comment: So you want to know how to choose the meshes you need to subdivide based on the position of the player?

Comment: Basically yes, but with always having all neigbour quads being subdivide one time less. Like in the second image.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing LOD subdivision on terrain is quite complicated, I rather recommend to use a library or something. But if you prefer to learn the hard way here are the principal steps you need to do:

First, unlike your assumption, you do not start with 6 meshes like the most zoomed out version, but you define your geometry at highest resolution *(most zoomed in version)*. So if we assume you implement 4 levels (0: lowest, 3: highest) you start with a sphere consisting of 4<sup>3</sup> * 6 = 384 meshes that is the entire sphere at level 3. Then you need the meshes for the lower levels. There are 4<sup>2</sup> * 6 meshes for level 2, 4<sup>1</sup> * 6 for level 1 and 4<sup>0</sup> * 6 for level 0, the simple cube. That gives you in total 510 meshes for all levels.

At runtime, you just determine the distance of each of your 384 level 3 meshes to the camera *(you may check only a subset)*. If the distance is long enough you render it with a lower level *(notice that you always join 4 predefined higher meshes into one lower level mesh)*. That's a basic LOD implementation.

Once you have finished this, you'll notice that the meshes at the border from one level to another are not properly connected and expose artifacts *(graphical glitches)*. To solve that too, you need **stitching**. The real pain of this topic *(interestingly your sphere image does show stitching already)*. So for stitching, you need extra border meshes for each level and side and corner which gives you an additional 8 fold mesh count ⇒ ~4590 meshes in total.

Actually, it's better you do not use something like generic meshes but using directly OpenGL *(or whatever)*. Which gives you additional flexibility (maybe some of those mesh implementations offer it too). In OpenGL this would result in just 384 buffer objects (sort of mesh container) and ~28 index buffers (sort of mesh layouts) and those can be combined at runtime to all the necessary *'meshes'*.

As I said, it is rather an advanced topic, you'll better searching for a guide to follow, or if you lost your need for pain, take a library already implementing it.